# Are questions about character development on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently watching a sci-fi show, and I've got some questions about the character development of one of the primary characters. Are these questions on topic?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't they be?

Answer (score 11):

## YES.

As long as the character comes from an already on-topic work.

We currently have a [character-development](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) tag with 67 questions with all but two having positive scores.

Also right in our tour in the "Ask about" section the first entry is

> Plot, **character**, or setting explanations.

[image]